# Issues with using higher capacitance than required

Tags: voltage-regulator, capacitance, linear-regulator

http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/stmicroelectronics/LD1117V33/497-1491-5-ND/586012

I am planning on using this regulator for a home project. I noticed on the datasheet that a minimum 10uF capacitance can be used. On the design diagram, they also have a 10uF listed.

What is the downfall of using a 22uF capacitor instead of the 10uF recommended capacitor? Is there a downfall at all? It is just a minimum recommending but I can go higher if I wanted to?

Thank you!

Comment: You can go higher. 10uF are needed for stability, and advertised in the reference circuit possibly because a smaller capacitance means a smaller capacitor, that costs less and takes less room on the pcb. Be aware that a bigger capacitor requires higher currents at startup.

Comment: In many of the applications in the datasheet you linked they use a higher capacitance on the input and on the output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, none. As long as you're above the minimum capacitance for stability, and the capacitor is relatively close to the regulator output (within a few cm), then you'll be alright. If anything, adding more capacitance will *generally* reduce the output noise.

The issue with "too much capacitance" comes in when you start getting into extreme capacitance values, in the range of Farads (not tens of microFarads like the cap you're talking about, but 1F). In that case, those capacitors take a lot of current for a long time to charge, which can cause a substantial amount of losses across your regulator, if it doesn't mistake the current draw as a short-circuit and shut itself off first.

Answer (score 3):

**22uF vs 10uF makes no difference. If you plan on doing step loads like 1A and want low ripple, then choose a Low ESR Cap.**

> A minimum Cap value is often to meet the noise level  in the specs. But it also affects step load ripple voltage.

The effect of this load Cap is a little hard to explain, but basically Cout lowers Zout with rising f while the regulator does the opposite due to internal loop gain BW limits.

We know the output impedance of an emitter follower depends on hFe and bias current. It also reduces with rising frequency due to Gain-bandwidth product, so Zout rises with f even with negative feedback, while C lowers Z(f) for rising f.

> Zout is the determining factor for output ripple with a step load R.  as an effective voltage divider.  The capacitor helps reduce noise, ripple and output impedance load regulation and in this design they specify no maximum. In other types using ultra low LDO's with MOSFET's , they often specify a maximum and minimum for instability reasons.

So the simple answer is 10uF is recommended to flatten the Zout and reduce step ripple error.  The static DC error for load regulation is 1mV drop from 5 to 800mA which translated into a 1/800 Ohm output impedance which probably rises to several Ohms at 100kHz, while the Cap does the opposite thus flattening the Zout response and improving step load ripple.